# Trying to build a visualforce page with columngrouping

Tags: visualforce

i have 4 fields (Agreemnt no, driver, period and sales). my db will be like following[image]

I want to built visualforce like following image

[image]

how can i fill sales based on period values

Answer (score 3):

can an agreement ever have data for more than one month? It doesn't appear so but this doesn't look like the optimal way of displaying those records either.

At the moment you can achieve what you want with code like the following but it's not exactly pretty

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!agreements}" var="a">
  <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
  <apex:column value="{!a.Driver__c}"/>
  <apex:column header="Jan">
    <apex:outputField value="{!a.Sales__c}" rendered="{!a.Period__c = 'jan'}"/>
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column header="Feb">
    <apex:outputField value="{!a.Sales__c}" rendered="{!a.Period__c = 'feb'}"/>
   <!-- etc for the other months --> 
  </apex:column>
```

If you only have one month of info per agreement then perhaps it'd be better to just have a Period column in the table, and output them by just doing:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!agreements}" var="a">
  <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
  <apex:column value="{!a.Driver__c}"/>
  <apex:column value="{!a.Period__c}"/>
  <apex:column value="{!a.Sales__c}"/>
</apex:PageBlockTable>
```

This makes the code more concise and removes empty space from the table itself. Ordering the query by driver and then period would probably give you useful groupings but it's hard to tell without knowing all of your requirements.